# Python f string handles new line differently between terminal and jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a function to print out the audio device information format into a table like f string.

This is an example:

```
line1 = (f"ID {'Device Name':25}{'INP':4}{'OUT':4}   SR   INP-(Lo|Hi)  OUT-(Lo/Hi) (Latency in ms)")
lines = [line1]

p1 = f"{0:<4g}{'INPUT':24}{'1':4}{'2':4}"
p2 = f"{'44100'}"
p3 = f"{'4.21'} {'10.33'}"
p4 = f"{'3.3'} {'6.6'}"
lines.append(p1 + p2 + p3 + p4)
```

In jupyter, `print(lines)` looks good with:

```
ID Device Name              INP OUT    SR   INP-(Lo|Hi)  OUT-(Lo/Hi) (Latency in ms)
0   INPUT                   1   2   441004.21 10.333.3 6.6
```

But in Terminal `print(lines)` becomes one long line.

```
['ID Device Name              INP OUT    SR   INP-(Lo|Hi)  OUT-(Lo/Hi) (Latency in ms)', '0   INPUT                   1   2   441004.21 10.333.3 6.6']
```

I had to join new line in order to break the line with:

```
lines = "\n".join(lines)
```

How can I have consistent print out in both terminal and jupyter ? Many thanks

Comment: Are you also calling `print(lines)` in terminal? If you just enter `lines`, what gets printed is the `repr` version. For strings, this displays all characters, including the literal `"\n"` characters.

Comment: yes, I am also calling print(lines) in terminal. And I get a long comma separated line

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this. I get the same output in my jupyter notebook as I do in terminal: `print(lines)` displays the list of lines (like you see in *your* terminal output).

Comment: @SyntaxVoid, yeah, you are right. I have a function to return lines. On Jupyter I just called the function and it printed the __repr__ version. Which is the format I want. So in terminal, is there a way I can print the __repr__ version ? I tried print(device_info().__repr__()) but no luck

Comment: You might consider a different option.  Try something like https://github.com/alttch/rapidtables to get nice tables.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, thanks but I would like to not introduce additional dependency for a small part of the package. But I probably reimplement it. Just thought it would be a simply issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a operator for this kind of print in python3 (not sure about python2) witch comes before list

```py
print(*lines, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

thats beacause you are not using print command in jupyter. if you want to get same output with print command both in jupyter and console try this:

```
  from IPython.display import display, HTML
  display(lines)
```

or

```
  display(HTML(lines.to_html()))
```